# How to catch error of rejected promise on client side?

Tags: node.js, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to have my server reject the `signup` request if the user tries to sign up with an existing account. However, I cant seem to reject it properly and pass the error message to my client side.

```
//server.js

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email
  const plainTextPassword = req.body.password;

  //check if user already exists 
  User.find({ email: email }, (err, existingUser) => {
    //account doesnt exist
    if (existingUser.length === 0) {
      bcrypt.hash(plainTextPassword, saltRounds, async (err, hash) => {
        try {
          const user = new User({
            email: email,
            password: hash
          });
          let result = await user.save();
          if (result) {
            res.send(result)
          }

        } catch (e) {
          res.send(e);
        }
      })
    } else {
      //notify user that account exists
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Account already exists'))
    }
  })

})
```

```
//reduxSlice.js
export const signup = createAsyncThunk(
    'userAuth/signup',
    async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        const { email, password } = payload
        try {
            const result = await fetch(
                signupPath, {
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'include',
                method: "post",
                body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
            )
            return result.json()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error) //this line executes
        }

    }
)
```

From my reduxdev tools, my `signup` is still fulfilled EVEN though I rejected it from my server. Also, my server crashes after one attempt, which leads me to suspect there is an uncaught error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client only receives what you do `res.send()` with or `next(err)` which will then call `res.send()`.  Promises are local only to the server and are not something that gets sent back to the client.

In your original code, I'd suggest that you use ONLY promise-based asynchronous operations and then you can `throw` in your code, have one place to catch all the errors and then send an error back to the client from there.

```
class ServerError extends Error {
    constructor(msg, status) {
        super(msg)
        this.status = status;
    }
}

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const email = req.body.email
        const plainTextPassword = req.body.password;

        //check if user already exists
        const existingUser = await User.find({ email: email });
        //account doesnt exist
        if (existingUser.length !== 0) {
            throw new ServerError('Account already exist', 403);
        }
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(plainTextPassword, saltRounds);
        const user = new User({
            email: email,
            password: hash
        });
        const result = await user.save();
        res.send(result);
    } catch (e) {
        if (!e.status) e.status = 500;
        console.log(e);
        res.status(e.status).send({err: e.message});
    }
});
```

Then, in your client code that is using `fetch()`, you need to check `result.ok` to see if you got a 2xx status back or not.  `fetch()` only rejects if the network connection to the target host failed.  If the connection succeeded, even if it returns an error status, the `fetch()` promise will resolve.  You have to examine `result.ok` to see if you got a 2xx status or not.

```
//reduxSlice.js
export const signup = createAsyncThunk(
    'userAuth/signup',
    async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        const { email, password } = payload
        try {
            const result = await fetch(
                signupPath, {
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'include',
                method: "post",
                body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
            // check to see if we got a 2xx status success
            if (!result.ok) {
                throw new Error(`signup failed: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return result.json()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error) //this line executes
        }

    }
)
```

Comment: thank you for the thorough explanation. it helps a lot!